# Tab Bar Controller does not display XIB UIViewController when tab is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Here is the scenario

Create new project Tabbed Application.  Add new controller, TestViewController with XIB file, in the XIB file just add one button with text "TestViewControllerButton".

If I create a button in FirstViewController, and add an action to go to TestViewController, the button in XIB file is displaed.

```
TestViewController* vc = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem is when I add TestViewController to tab controller (index 2, start from 0), it does not show the XIB (I mean, the button does not displayed).

Here are my steps.  I add UIViewController in Tab Controller, then change the class to TestViewController in Identity Inspector.  Then add Tab Bar Item to TestViewController and link it to Tab Bar Controller, so when the last tab is clicked, it linked to TestViewController.  But the problem is, the button in the XIB is not displayed (I add the button in TestViewController.xib).

Yeah, off course I can add the button directly in Main.storyboard in my TestViewController, but the idea is I want to manage the UI in TestViewController XIB, and the main.storyboard just load the view in TestViewController image.

Ok, I add some screenshot to make understand.  This screen runs well when I do programmatically, run in UIViewController (code above - self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil).

[image: Run in UiViewController]

When I run from Tab

[image]

The setting I think is already correct (since it runs well in UIViewController)

[image: Main storyboard custom class controller]

Already set file owner to the TestViewController

[image: File Owner]

Already bind the outlet

[image: Outlet]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it will not show the controls. See, you are using two different view controllers at these places. In the xib, you have actually added your button and hence when an instance of your `testViewController` is created from the xib, it has the button and its associated action with it. However, in the case when you add a `viewController` in your storyboard and set its class to be that of `TestViewController`, all you are doing is setting the class type of the new `view controller` to be `TestViewController`. But you are not providing any information by which the storyboard can know that it has to create the new instance of `testViewController` from the image saved in its XIB. So it just crates a new view controller of type `TestViewController`, using its image from inside the storyboard (without the button in it).

So to get your view controller from the xib you will have to override `initWithCoder:` method inside your `TestViewController` implementation and return an instance of your viewController from the XIB. Something like:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  return [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}
```

Comment: yeah, actually this is nearly solved, but there are 2 more questions: 1. The icon tab is missing after I added the code,  how to restore that, see http://punyaku.com/ios/noTabIcon.png.  2.  Is there any functionality to load the XIB in TestViewController.viewDidLoad method?  The TestViewController is extends from UIViewController.   If the UI is extends from UITableViewController, to register the XIB to UITableViewCell, I can use [self.tableView registerNib...] in viewDidLoad method.  Is there any same functionality to do that?  Will upvote & mark as answer after these answers.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the ViewController of size Inferred , Change it to iPhone 4 inch  in Attribute Inspector (Simulated Metrics -> Size and set the button  frame acc. to that .

[image]        [image]

Hope this help :)

Comment: @Jef - you can download sample Code and let me  know it that Ok .                 Link - https://github.com/ArpitLokwani/ALTabbedBarSample

Comment: it is not ok.  My problem is, how to separate the View (there is a button TestViewControllerButton) in your View Controller Scene to a separate XIB.  Not just put a button in existing main storyboard, I already mention in my issue before.  I think your solution is slightly different from my problem, since in your sample there is no my provided screenshot too.